# What will happen to MLAs who were missing for the Karnataka CM HD floor test?

Tags: constitution, parliament, india, karnataka

On the floor test day BJP garnered 105 votes of the required 103 since only 205 MLAs (Members of the Legislative Assembly), out of the full capacity of 222 MLAs, were present on the floor.

What will happen to those 17 MLAs who were missing on the floor test? Do they continue to be part of the government, or will the house function with only 205 MLAs until the term ends?

Answer (score 1):

You are misinformed with the numbers. Before the high voltage drama began, there were 225 members in the Assembly. 17 of the MLAs involved in the controversy stood [disqualified](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/karnataka/karnataka-speaker-disqualifies-more-rebel-mlas-till-end-of-assembly-term/article28737298.ece) by the then Speaker K. R. Ramesh Kumar on grounds of disqualification under Schedule X of the Indian Constitution. This brought the strength of the Assembly from 225 to 208, and BJP had 105, which was above the simply majority to stake claim in the formation of the Government.

To know what disqualification has cost those MLAs, follow my answer [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/43084/5306).